# canvas cropping image to square after orientating in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, crop

I am using this function to orientate, resize and compress the user submitted image.
In case of phone taken pictures are rectangular. I need to get a square image out of the original one cropping it after rotation. How to do it?

```
function resetOrientationResizeCompress(srcBase64, srcOrientation) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve) {

        var img = new Image();

        img.onload = function () {
            var width = img.width,
                height = img.height,
                canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
                ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            var MAX_WIDTH = 1000;
            var MAX_HEIGHT = 1000;

            // set proper canvas dimensions before transform & export
            if ([5, 6, 7, 8].indexOf(srcOrientation) > -1) {
                if (width > height) {
                    if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                        height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                        width = MAX_WIDTH;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                        width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                        height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                    }
                }
                canvas.width = height;
                canvas.height = width;
            } else {
                if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                    width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                    height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                }
                canvas.width = width;
                canvas.height = height;
            }

            // transform context before drawing image
            switch (srcOrientation) {
                case 2:
                    ctx.transform(-1, 0, 0, 1, width, 0);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    ctx.transform(-1, 0, 0, -1, width, height);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, height);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    ctx.transform(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    ctx.transform(0, 1, -1, 0, height, 0);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    ctx.transform(0, -1, -1, 0, height, width);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    ctx.transform(0, -1, 1, 0, 0, width);
                    break;
                default:
                    ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
            }

            // draw image
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

            // export base64
            resolve(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.6));
        };

        img.src = srcBase64;

    })

}
```

I was able to modify the function so that after orientation the image gets cropped to a square. I tried with images that had orientation 1 and 6. Could I be missing something here for more cases? Here's the code:

```
function resetOrientationResizeCompress(srcBase64, srcOrientation) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve) {

        var img = new Image();

        img.onload = function () {
            var width = img.width,
                height = img.height,
                canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
                ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
                start_Y,
                start_X;

            var MAX_WIDTH = 1000;
            var MAX_HEIGHT = 1000;

            //srcOrientation is defined
            if(srcOrientation){

                // set proper canvas dimensions before transform & export
                if ([5, 6, 7, 8].indexOf(srcOrientation) > -1) {
                    if (width > height) {
                        if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                            height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                            width = MAX_WIDTH;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                            width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                            height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                        }
                    }
                    canvas.width = height;
                    canvas.height = width;
                } else {
                    if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                        width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                        height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                    }
                    canvas.width = width;
                    canvas.height = height;
                }

            }
            //srcOrientation undefined
            else{

                if (width > height) {
                    if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                        height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                        width = MAX_WIDTH;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                        width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                        height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                    }
                }
                canvas.width = height;
                canvas.height = width;


            }


            //crop image for different cases (vertical, horizontal, square image)
            if(canvas.width < canvas.height){

                console.log('vertical');

                start_Y = (canvas.height - canvas.width)/2;

                start_X = 0;

                canvas.height = canvas.width;

            }
            else if(canvas.width > canvas.height){

                console.log('horizontal');

                start_Y = (canvas.width - canvas.height)/2;

                start_X = 0;

                canvas.width = canvas.height;

            }
            else if(canvas.width == canvas.height){

                console.log('square');

                start_Y = 0;

                start_X = 0;
            }

            // orientate image if orientation is defined
            if(srcOrientation){

                // transform context before drawing image
                switch (srcOrientation) {
                    case 2:
                        ctx.transform(-1, 0, 0, 1, width, 0);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        ctx.transform(-1, 0, 0, -1, width, height);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, height);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        ctx.transform(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        ctx.transform(0, 1, -1, 0, height, 0);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        ctx.transform(0, -1, -1, 0, height, width);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        ctx.transform(0, -1, 1, 0, 0, width);
                        break;
                    default:
                        ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
                }

            }

            // draw image
            ctx.drawImage(img, -start_Y, start_X, width, height);

            // export base64
            resolve(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.6));
        };

        img.src = srcBase64;

    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The absolute easiest solution, If you don't care about actually editing the image and you know the exact crop size, is simply draw the picture starting at a negative coordinate so that left or top part of the image is off the canvas. Alternatively you can make the canvas small enough so that, when drawing at x=y=0, the right or bottom half is cut off. In either case, it's about sizing the canvas to the size you want the picture, and positioning it so that the area you don't want is cutoff.

Alternatively, there are amazing libraries like cropper.js that can give the user a lot of freedom to crop. I know with cropper.js you can restrict the crop to a square and have the user drag that square to where they want to crop

Comment: I need to get the center of the picture if rectangular so cut the outer parts. example it 1500 s 1000 I need to cut 250 left and right and get 1000 x 1000. I think I can maybe do this checking the original W and H and then set a variable to get the center of the longest side and calculate the starting x and  y of the resulting image

Comment: So then the first method I mentioned should work. To cut a 1500px wide image by 250 left and right, try making the canvas 1000px wide and placing the image -250 on the x axis. Or, in function form,

canvas.width  = img.width-(croppingArea*2)

 and then
ctx.drawImage(img, -croppingArea, 0, width, height);

Comment: You don't know the croppingArea as you don't kmow what size the picture will be. CroppingArea = (height - width)/2 or viceversa if width > height

Comment: I was able to modify the function so that it crops the resulting oriented image into a square of max 1000*1000 pixels.